# How to get a list of all subclasses of a particular class/entity from Hibernate metadata?

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say I have this Hibernate definition (or similar):

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">   
  <class name=“class1” table=“table1”>
    <id name="id" column=“column1” type="long">
    </id>
    <discriminator type="string">
      <column name=“type” />
    </discriminator>
    <subclass name=“class2”>
      <subclass name=“class3”> </subclass>
    </subclass>   
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I'd like to get a list of subclasses for `class1` from Hibernate metadata.
I could only find `subclassesByDiscriminatorValue` field in `SingleTableEntityPersister`, but it's not public. Is there any public API for that? Please note that I need to get a list of subclasses in Hibernate sense, not in Java sense.

Comment: How do you define a subclass "in the Hibernate sense"?  If it's just based on the `<subclass...>` tags in the XML, then you can parse the XML and build the tree yourself relatively easily.

Comment: @JimGarrison A subclass defined as a subclass in Hibernate configuration. As far as I understand It may or may not be a subclass of a base class (as defined in Hibernate) on Java level.

Comment: @JimGarrison I don't want to parse XML and get subclasses from it manually. It can be defined in XML, can be defined as annotations etc. Hibernate already has this information in its metadata, but from what I can see it's not public. I'm wondering if there is a way to get it through public API somehow.

Comment: You'll probably have to read through the Hibernate code to find its internal model.  If there's no public API and you have to "hack" access to it, you'll be vulnerable to the model changing in the future.  This question is probably more appropriate for the [Hibernate Community Forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually found an answer - it is `EntityMetamodel.getSubclassEntityNames()`